# How to make a for loop use 2 strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, slice

I have 2 strings I wish to compare. The issue is I do not know how to slice both iterativly at the same time and then run the comparison code on each slice.Below is my code which I have attempted to run by using a for loop within a for loop (one for each string) which didnt bring up any errors but only the first string was iterativly sliced and printed to screen. The second attempt was to merge the 2 for loops together however the error message provided occured which explains the reason it failed clearly, however I dont know a method around the error.

Code for for loop in for loop

```
for i in range(8, len(seq1)):
    seq1i = seq1[0:i]
    print seq1i

    for i in range(8,len(seq2)):
        seq2i = seq2[0:i]
        print seq2i

        for c1, c2 in zip(seq1i, seq2i):
            if c1 == c2:
                counter += 1
            else:
                break
        print "String share the longest common prefix of length %d: %s" % (counter, seq1[:counter])
        if counter >= 8:
            print " Match found, match length %d" % counter
```

Attempt at merging the for loops:

```
for i1,i2 in range(8,len(seq1, seq2)):
    for c1, c2 in zip(seq1i, seq2i):
        if c1 == c2:
            counter += 1
        else:
            break
    print "String share the longest common prefix of length %d: %s" % (counter, seq1[:counter])
    if counter >= 8:
        print " Match found, match length %d" % counter
```

This caused the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-9c4822069792> in <module>()
----> 1 for i1,i2 in range(8,len(seq1, seq2)):
      2     for c1, c2 in zip(seq1i, seq2i):
      3         if c1 == c2:
      4             counter += 1
      5         else:

TypeError: len() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

I figure there must be a method where each iterative slicing of the strings will occur and as they are made the matching ( if c1 == c2) code can be run.

The wanted output would be :

if seq1 and seq2:

```
seq1 = 'ATCGATCGATCGAAAA'
seq2 = 'ATCGATCGATCCCCCC'

A
A
AT
AT
ATC
ATC
ATCG
ATCG
ATCGA
ATCGA
ATCGAT
ATCGAT
ATCGATC
ATCGATC
ATCGATCG
ATCGATCG
ATCGATCGA
ATCGATCGA
ATCGATCGAT
ATCGATCGAT
ATCGATCGATC
ATCGATCGATC
String share the longest common prefix of length 10:ATCGATCGATC
```

Comment: What do you want to do basically?

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there are fancier solutions using advanced slicing and/or itertools, but honestly, I think a simple loop is the easiest thing here.

```
for i, c in enumerate(seq1):
    try:
        if c != seq2[i]:
            break
        print seq1[:i + 1] + '\n' + seq1[:i + 1]
    except IndexError:
        break
print 'Longest common prefix %s of length %d' % (seq1[:i], i)
```

Comment: It's possible to get an indexing error if `seq1` is longer than `seq2`.

Comment: @martineau That's why the `if` is wrapped in a `try`.

Answer (score 4):

Despite being from the `os.path` module, you should use `os.path.commonprefix` for this.

```
>> s1 = 'GATTACA'
>> s2 = 'GATTCCC'
>> os.path.commonprefix([s1,s2])
'GATT'
```

Comment: As long as you remember to write a very clear comment... talk about obscure code usage...

Comment: I can understand why it would seem obscure and I agree that it would be nice to have a library function in some module that is not `os.path`, but there is no reason to reinvent the wheel to do common prefixes.

Comment: Except that it is a very simple wheel, and it's reinvention makes your code much clearer...

Comment: @SilasRay I don't know that I agree with you there. Using a method from stdlib, even if it's categorized as `os.path` and used for something else, does not make any less sense than writing a new custom function (for which you would ALSO have to document) to have the same function.

Comment: And as this question might suggest, there are a few ways to reinvent the wheel incorrectly. I agree though that it is annoying, and should definitely be somewhere else (if you google, you will find people that are very annoyed that it only does string manipulation and does not do smarter path checking, personally I have just sort of made a mental note that `os.path.commonprefix` is not actually part of `os.path`)

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that was there. Nothing ambiguous about a function named ```commonprefix```.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually `zip` strings, which seems much more pythonic than most of the answers here:

```
str1 = 'ACTGGAG'
str2 = 'ACTA'

prefix = ''
for a,b in zip(str1,str2):
    if a==b:
        prefix += a
    else:
        break

print prefix # prints ACT
```

Comment: Is it possible to set a matching exception so if a or b = 'N' it continues as a match?

Comment: sure, simply change "a==b" to "a==b or a=='N' or b=='N'" or add another if if you want some special behaviour (like adding special char to prefix)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit inefficient to print the intermediate results, but this seem to work:

```
def lcp(seq1, seq2):
    ret = []
    for i in xrange(min(len(seq1), len(seq1))):
        if seq1[i] != seq2[i]:
            break
        else:
            ret.append(seq1[i])
            print ''.join(ret)
    print "strings share a longest common prefix of length:", len(ret)

seq1 = 'ATCGATCGATCGAAAA'
seq2 = 'ATCGATCGATCCCCCC'
lcp(seq1, seq2)
```

Output:

```
A
AT
ATC
ATCG
ATCGA
ATCGAT
ATCGATC
ATCGATCG
ATCGATCGA
ATCGATCGAT
ATCGATCGATC
strings share a longest common prefix of length: 11
```